# MailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor returns Nothing

Tags: vb.net, outlook, ms-office

I'm composing an email using VB.Net which is opened in `Outlook 2013`. I need to the contents to be displayed in its default font which is set by the user.

Now i need to get the default font and set to the email. When i tried it returns `null` at one place.

//Code:

```
Private m_valDefaultFontSpec As DefaultFont

Sub GetDefaultFontSpec(Optional blnGetReplyFont As Boolean = False)

    Dim objDoc As Document
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim objDummy As MailItem

    On Error Resume Next

    '  Create a "dummy" mail object,
    Set objDummy = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    '  Get the document object from the current "dummy mail" object.
    Set objDoc = objDummy.GetInspector.WordEditor //returns nothing here

    '  Get the range of the word document object.
    Set rng = objDoc.Range

    '  Get some font properties from the given range.
    With rng
        m_valDefaultFontSpec.Name = .Font.Name
        m_valDefaultFontSpec.Size = .Font.Size
        m_valDefaultFontSpec.Bold = .Font.Bold
        m_valDefaultFontSpec.Color = .Font.Color
        m_valDefaultFontSpec.Italic = .Font.Italic
    End With

    '  Finished with the "dummy" mail, close it.
    objDummy.Close olDiscard

    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Where am i wrong? Any help?

[Source](http://www.outlookcode.com/codedetail.aspx?id=2085)

Comment: At which point do you get null? Is it the rng which is null?

Answer (score 0):

`WordEditor` property might not be available until the message is shown.

Try to simply set the `MailItem.HTMLBody` property.

Comment: I need to get the default font that is set by the user during composing email. Right now all defaults to TimesNewRoman. Where/How can i get the default font?

Comment: Why not explicitly specify the right font when you set HTMLBody?

Comment: The right font is user defined one. So i need to get it from somewhere in Outlook(Like in the code).

Comment: User specified font is stored in the ComposeFontComplex and ComposeFontSimple registry keys in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\xx.0\Common\MailSettings (where xx is the Outlook version, e.g. 15 for OUtlook 2013).

Comment: Do u have any code to retrieve the font and get used?

Comment: I do not. You'd need to parse that blob.