# Scheduled recurring email

Tags: vba, email, outlook

The code below does not give compilation errors but does not send emails.

The purpose is to send recurring emails by linking them to appointments.

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim xMailItem As MailItem
Dim xItemDoc As Word.Document
Dim xNewDoc As Word.Document
On Error Resume Next
If Item.Class <> OlObjectClass.olAppointment Then Exit Sub
If Item.Categories <> "Send Schedule Recurring Email" Then Exit Sub
Set xMailItem = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set xItemDoc = Item.GetInspector.WordEditor
xItemDoc.Activate
xItemDoc.Application.Selection.WholeStory
xItemDoc.Application.Selection.Copy
With xMailItem
    .To = Item.Location
    .Subject = Item.Subject
    Set xNewDoc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
    xNewDoc.Activate
    xNewDoc.Application.Selection.HomeKey
    xNewDoc.Content.Paste
    .Send
End With
Set xMailItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

It seems that the problem is in Item.Class. I receive a message that says

> Invalid outside procedure.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please debug your code before asking a question. You might find the solution through the debugging process and if you don't you can tell us exactly where the code fails and you will be able to ask a better question. Read this VBA debugging guide: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Comment: Then read the how to ask guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This will lead to less frustration and get you the information you want faster.

Comment: The reason you get no errors is you told it to ignore all errors with this line: ```On Error Resume Next``` Remove that and see what the error is.

Comment: Thank you Warcupine it seems that the problem is in Item.Class. I receive a message that says Invalid outside procedure. What does it means? Sorry but I'm still learning VBA

Comment: I don't see what ```item``` actually is so I'm assuming that it was a variable you defined somewhere else and are trying to use in this sub, which would make it out of scope if it isn't passed as an argument or defined as a global.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I did a bit of flirting and I found some useful tips, I finally solved it as follows:

```
Dim WithEvents objReminders As Outlook.Reminders
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim MItem As MailItem
Set MItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
If Item.MessageClass <> "IPM.Appointment" Then Exit Sub
If Item.Categories <> "Send Schedule Recurring Email" Then Exit Sub
MItem.To = Item.Location
MItem.CC = ""
MItem.BCC = ""
MItem.Subject = Item.Subject
MItem.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
Item.GetInspector().WordEditor.Range.Copy
MItem.GetInspector().WordEditor.Range.Paste
MItem.Display
MItem.Send
Set MItem = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Set objReminders = Application.Reminders
End Sub
Private Sub objReminders_ReminderFire(ByVal ReminderOBject As Reminder)

If ReminderOBject.Item.Categories <> "Send Schedule Recurring Email" Then Exit Sub

ReminderOBject.Dismiss

End Sub
```

I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

The answer by [Umberto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61085245/4249483) is correct, but there is a minor error.

`Item.GetInspector() -> Item.GetInspector`

```
Item.GetInspector.WordEditor.Range.Copy
MItem.GetInspector.WordEditor.Range.Paste
```

Some sources that brought me to this fix:

- [MailItem.GetInspector property (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.getinspector)
- [MailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor returns Nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119333/mailitem-getinspector-wordeditor-returns-nothing)